# Ring of polynomial functions on unit hyperbola is PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ be the ring of polynomial functions pn the unit hyperbola. How do I prove that $R$ is a principal ideal domain with unit group $$R^*=\{cX^i\text{mod}(XY-1):c\in\mathbb{R}^*,i\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cong\mathbb{R}^*\times<X>?$$

I know that $R$ is isomorphic with the ring of Laurent polynomials, but how can I use that?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you know that $\mathbb R[X]$ is a PID.  Now your ring is equal to $\mathbb R[X,X^{-1}]$ (sitting inside $\mathbb R(X)$).  It is an easy exercise to prove that if $A$ is a PID and $a$ is a non-zero element of $A$, then $A[1/a]$ is a PID.

As for the unit group, what are the units in $\mathbb R[X]$?  Which additional elements become invertible when you invert $X$?

(You could consider the analogy with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[1/2]$.)

Comment: The units in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ are the polynomials $1/X$?

Comment: @Jean-Claude $1/X\notin\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: @Slade What are the units then?

Comment: @Jean-Claude They are the polynomials $f(X)$ such that there exists $g(X)$ with $f(X)g(X)=1$.  To characterize them, think about the degree of both sides of that equation.

Comment: @Slade degree of f is inverse of degree of g?

Comment: @Jean-Claude The additive inverse, yes.  And which non-negative integers have an additive inverse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32584/discussion-between-jean-claude-and-slade).

Answer (score -1):

A principal ideal domain is a ring where every nonzero prime ideal has height one. First notice that $(XY-1)$ is a prime ideal. And any prime ideal $p$ of the ring $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(XY-1)}$ is in one to one correspondence to the prime ideals of the ring $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ containing $(XY-1)$. 
  Now as the dimension of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ is 2 so any nonzero prime ideal of $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(XY-1)}$ has height 1, hence it is a PID.

Comment: As for the answer, there seem to be some nontrivial facts being used implicitly here.  For example, it is true that any UFD where every nonzero prime has height 1 is a PID, but we have to do some work to show that this ring is a UFD.  Perhaps it is better to use this theorem: An integral domain is a PID if and only if every prime ideal is principal.  But this still requires some work.

Comment: @GGT "*A principal ideal domain is a ring where every nonzero prime ideal has height one.*" It's right that in a PID every nonzero prime ideal has height one, but you are using the converse when say "*so any nonzero prime ideal of $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(XY-1)}$ has height 1, hence it is a PID.*" Unfortunately the converse is wrong: $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is one of the many counterexamples. (-1)

Comment: Well thanks for the comment. I have to prove first the quotient ring is unique factorization domain. If the ring is UFD converse will work.